# How to reset/control transition delay when hover out?

Tags: html, css

So, here is my simple example about `transition-delay`. When I hover over the `div`, another `p` text lands from above with a 0.6s delay. But when I hover out, it also goes with the same 0.6s delay - as expected.

I want it to transition from above as landing, but reset the 0.6s `transition-delay`. I want it to goes without any `transition-delay`.

Note that I am using the transition in `.hidden` that's why it's happening. But I don't want to put it in `.hidden:hover` since it'll not work correctly... you know.

Here is my jsbin - [My Simple Hoverable Problem](https://jsbin.com/tufifaxamu/)

```css
/* Just for decoration ^_^ */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap');

/* I always reset :) */
* {
  padding: 0; 
  margin: 0; 
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
body {
  font-family: "open sans", verdana; 
}

/* main problem starts here... */
div {
  width: 20rem;
  padding: 5rem; 
  margin: 2rem; 
  background: dodgerblue; 
  cursor: pointer; 
}

.hidden {
  transform: translateY(-2000%); 
  transition: 0.6s ease-out 0.6s; 
}

div:hover .hidden {
  transform: translateY(0); 
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p class="hidden">How Are You? </p>
</div>
```

**Note:** I already searched it but didn't find any relevant answer but I think there might be one. Maybe I am too lazy to dig deeper. In that case, kindly mention the similar thread. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to remove the `0.6` second delay, you need to remove the second parameter `0.6` from `transition: 0.6s ease-out 0.6s`, class `.hidden`.

As a result, it should look like this:

```
.hidden {
  transform: translateY(-2000%); 
  transition: 0.6s ease-out; 
}
```

```css
/* Just for decoration ^_^ */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap');

/* I always reset :) */
* {
  padding: 0; 
  margin: 0; 
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
body {
  font-family: "open sans", verdana; 
}

/* main problem starts here... */
div {
  width: 20rem;
  padding: 5rem; 
  margin: 2rem; 
  background: dodgerblue; 
  cursor: pointer; 
}

.hidden {
  transform: translateY(-2000%); 
  transition: 0.6s ease-out; 
}

div:hover .hidden {
  transform: translateY(0); 
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p class="hidden">How Are You? </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, seems like translateY do the trick. But you don't understand, man. My main pen is here - [link](https://codepen.io/forhad2002/pen/wvzgOXz) Now see, is it necessary or not.

Comment: Ok, thanks man. translateY trick is actually working! Marking as accepted. [Why can't I sometime use my brain...? ]

Comment: I gave a description of what I did, bro. To remove the delay from the main pen, you need to find the selector - `.wrapper: hover .meta-data {}`, and remove the `0.4s` parameter from the `transition: 0.6s ease 0.4s`

Comment: I put that just for test. But the hovering is working with `0.6s ease 0.4s`. Hover the mouse - Land the author name & date after 0.4s of mouse hovering. Then hover out - the texts goes with that without any delay. Not quite sure though what I actually doing. A lot of code mess me up -__-

Comment: Again, thanks for your valuable time. My honor to meet such a senior developer :)

Comment: @ForhadRahman, I am also glad to meet you, and always happy to help :)